# symfony - configure postgres entity manager

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to change the database in my existing project from mysql to postgresql.
I have configured the database, I have regenerated the migrations which work, but the problem appears in the fixtures.
when trying to load fixtures an error appears like this:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (nickname, password, id, created_at, updated_at, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["user", "$2y$13$rgHtT56Vlk2  
  avmf3gX2W7.QYcQ5d6AXRzr41ebRMGfxREqLZQfsTG", "017c4562-d487-ddff-c303-108c1916d6dd", "2021-10-03 11:01:16", "2021-10-03 11:01:16", "user@user.pl"]:                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 BŁĄD:  błąd składni w lub blisko "user"                                                                                                             
  LINE 1: INSERT INTO user (nickname, password, id, created_at, update...         ,
```

this is a problem possibly caused by entity manager generating the mysql dialect instead of  postgres dialect.
a similar error occurs during the get shot under the user entity:

```
"hydra:description": "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT u0_.nickname AS nickname_0, u0_.password AS password_1, u0_.id AS id_2, u0_.created_at AS created_at_3, u0_.updated_at AS updated_at_4, u0_.email AS email_5 FROM user u0_':\n\nSQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 BŁĄD:  kolumna u0_.nickname nie istnieje\nLINE 1: SELECT u0_.nickname AS nickname_0, u0_.password AS password_.
```

Here is my doctrine.yaml configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
        charset: utf8

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Could someone help me get rid of the bug? :)

Comment: User is reserved keyword in postgres. You can change table name to avoid error. ```/** @Entity @Table(name="users") */
class User { ... }```

Comment: Oh, you're right! I never thought that could be the reason, thank you!